# How to use regular expression to match just bracket?

Tags: regex, regular-language

Here, I want to use regular expression to replace all my code in Visual Studio like  `table.append(QString::fromLocal8Bit("test_code"));` into just 
`table.append("test_code");`

So I think the rule should be first match "QString::fromLocal8Bit(",which should be `QString::fromLocal8Bit\(` in reg code.  But I stuck at how to just skip some chars here until the first ")".

By the way, is there a regular expression website  that could just output the regular pattern by inputting  (several)  pairs of original statements and the expected statements?

Comment: Websites for testing regular expressions: https://regexr.com/, https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *capture* the argument, or whatever that is (the `"test_code"`) in a capturing group, and then replace the whole matched substring with that captured group:

```
QString::fromLocal8Bit\((.*?)\)
```

Replace with:

```
$1
```

(that is, replace with the first captured group)

https://regex101.com/r/Muj7i6/1

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in VS, it just replace each matched statement with "\1".

Comment: Oops, I think the syntax in VSCode is `$1` instead of `\1`, can you try that?

Comment: Oh, I just googled and found it told me use `$1` from here:https://mattfrear.com/2012/09/05/regular-expression-replace-in-visual-studio/,  anyway, thanks~